# Paintcode and Snap SVG

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, snap.svg, paintcode

I am trying to bridge examples from [Paintcode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SE2tmgYbCU) and [Snap SVG](http://snapsvg.io/docs/).

[Here](http://yepher.com/svgGearExample/slider.html) is a simple project that has the gears that spin when a slider is dragged. This is great but I would like to do the interaction with the mouse instead.

This is an example of the gears as svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="200"  xml:space="preserve" id="gears">
    <!-- Generated by PaintCode - http://www.paintcodeapp.com -->
    <path id="gears-largeGear" stroke="none" fill="rgb(69, 131, 212)" d="M 2.78,-67.94 C 3.71,-63.88 4.74,-59.43 5.59,-55.72 7.73,-55.51 9.84,-55.18 11.9,-54.73 13.87,-58 16.21,-61.91 18.36,-65.49 20.15,-64.99 21.91,-64.42 23.64,-63.78 23.27,-59.62 22.87,-55.08 22.54,-51.28 24.5,-50.42 26.4,-49.45 28.23,-48.37 31.11,-50.87 34.55,-53.87 37.69,-56.6 39.24,-55.58 40.73,-54.49 42.18,-53.34 40.55,-49.5 38.77,-45.3 37.28,-41.79 38.87,-40.37 40.37,-38.87 41.79,-37.28 45.3,-38.77 49.5,-40.55 53.34,-42.18 54.49,-40.73 55.58,-39.24 56.6,-37.69 53.87,-34.55 50.87,-31.11 48.37,-28.23 49.45,-26.4 50.42,-24.5 51.28,-22.54 55.08,-22.87 59.62,-23.27 63.78,-23.64 64.42,-21.91 64.99,-20.15 65.49,-18.36 61.91,-16.21 58,-13.87 54.73,-11.9 55.18,-9.84 55.51,-7.73 55.72,-5.59 59.43,-4.74 63.88,-3.71 67.94,-2.78 67.98,-1.86 68,-0.93 68,0 68,0.93 67.98,1.86 67.94,2.78 63.88,3.71 59.43,4.74 55.72,5.59 55.51,7.73 55.18,9.84 54.73,11.9 58,13.87 61.91,16.21 65.49,18.36 64.99,20.15 64.42,21.91 63.78,23.64 59.62,23.27 55.08,22.87 51.28,22.54 50.42,24.5 49.45,26.4 48.37,28.23 50.87,31.11 53.87,34.55 56.6,37.69 55.58,39.24 54.49,40.73 53.34,42.18 49.5,40.55 45.3,38.77 41.79,37.28 40.37,38.87 38.87,40.37 37.28,41.79 38.77,45.3 40.55,49.5 42.18,53.34 40.73,54.49 39.24,55.58 37.69,56.6 34.55,53.87 31.11,50.87 28.23,48.37 26.4,49.45 24.5,50.42 22.54,51.28 22.87,55.08 23.27,59.62 23.64,63.78 21.91,64.42 20.15,64.99 18.36,65.49 16.21,61.91 13.87,58 11.9,54.73 9.84,55.18 7.73,55.51 5.59,55.72 4.74,59.43 3.71,63.88 2.78,67.94 1.86,67.98 0.93,68 -0,68 -0.93,68 -1.86,67.98 -2.78,67.94 -3.71,63.88 -4.74,59.43 -5.59,55.72 -7.73,55.51 -9.84,55.18 -11.9,54.73 -13.87,58 -16.21,61.91 -18.36,65.49 -20.15,64.99 -21.91,64.42 -23.64,63.78 -23.27,59.62 -22.87,55.08 -22.54,51.28 -24.5,50.42 -26.4,49.45 -28.23,48.37 -31.11,50.87 -34.55,53.87 -37.69,56.6 -39.24,55.58 -40.73,54.49 -42.18,53.34 -40.55,49.5 -38.77,45.3 -37.28,41.79 -38.87,40.37 -40.37,38.87 -41.79,37.28 -45.3,38.77 -49.5,40.55 -53.34,42.18 -54.49,40.73 -55.58,39.24 -56.6,37.69 -53.87,34.55 -50.87,31.11 -48.37,28.23 -49.45,26.4 -50.42,24.5 -51.28,22.54 -55.08,22.87 -59.62,23.27 -63.78,23.64 -64.42,21.91 -64.99,20.15 -65.49,18.36 -61.91,16.21 -58,13.87 -54.73,11.9 -55.18,9.84 -55.51,7.73 -55.72,5.59 -59.43,4.74 -63.88,3.71 -67.94,2.78 -67.98,1.86 -68,0.93 -68,-0 -68,-0.93 -67.98,-1.86 -67.94,-2.78 -63.88,-3.71 -59.43,-4.74 -55.72,-5.59 -55.51,-7.73 -55.18,-9.84 -54.73,-11.9 -58,-13.87 -61.91,-16.21 -65.49,-18.36 -64.99,-20.15 -64.42,-21.91 -63.78,-23.64 -59.62,-23.27 -55.08,-22.87 -51.28,-22.54 -50.42,-24.5 -49.45,-26.4 -48.37,-28.23 -50.87,-31.11 -53.87,-34.55 -56.6,-37.69 -55.58,-39.24 -54.49,-40.73 -53.34,-42.18 -49.5,-40.55 -45.3,-38.77 -41.79,-37.28 -40.37,-38.87 -38.87,-40.37 -37.28,-41.79 -38.77,-45.3 -40.55,-49.5 -42.18,-53.34 -41.55,-53.84 -40.91,-54.33 -40.26,-54.81 -39.42,-55.43 -38.56,-56.03 -37.69,-56.6 -34.55,-53.87 -31.11,-50.87 -28.23,-48.37 -26.4,-49.45 -24.5,-50.42 -22.54,-51.28 -22.87,-55.08 -23.27,-59.62 -23.64,-63.78 -21.91,-64.42 -20.15,-64.99 -18.36,-65.49 -16.21,-61.91 -13.87,-58 -11.9,-54.73 -9.84,-55.18 -7.73,-55.51 -5.59,-55.72 -4.74,-59.43 -3.71,-63.88 -2.78,-67.94 -1.93,-67.98 -1.08,-68 -0.23,-68 L 0,-68 C 0.93,-68 1.86,-67.98 2.78,-67.94 Z M 0,-36 C -6.22,-36 -12.07,-34.42 -17.18,-31.65 -28.39,-25.55 -36,-13.66 -36,-0 -36,19.88 -19.88,36 0,36 19.88,36 36,19.88 36,-0 36,-19.88 19.88,-36 0,-36 Z M 0,-36" transform="translate(150, 96) rotate(-0.5)"  />
    <path id="gears-smallGear" stroke="none" fill="rgb(115, 152, 218)" d="M 2.12,-37.94 L 2.45,-37.92 C 3.29,-34.48 4.2,-30.71 4.97,-27.56 6.23,-27.34 7.46,-27.03 8.65,-26.64 9.87,-26.24 11.04,-25.77 12.18,-25.22 14.65,-27.32 17.61,-29.83 20.31,-32.12 21.69,-31.25 23.02,-30.28 24.27,-29.24 22.92,-25.96 21.45,-22.37 20.22,-19.37 21.97,-17.55 23.47,-15.49 24.68,-13.24 27.91,-13.49 31.78,-13.78 35.32,-14.05 35.92,-12.54 36.42,-10.99 36.83,-9.39 33.81,-7.53 30.5,-5.49 27.75,-3.79 27.91,-2.55 28,-1.29 28,-0 28,1.29 27.91,2.55 27.75,3.79 30.51,5.49 33.81,7.53 36.83,9.39 36.42,10.99 35.92,12.54 35.32,14.05 31.78,13.78 27.91,13.49 24.68,13.24 23.47,15.49 21.97,17.55 20.22,19.37 21.45,22.37 22.92,25.96 24.27,29.24 23.02,30.28 21.69,31.25 20.31,32.12 17.61,29.83 14.65,27.32 12.18,25.22 9.93,26.31 7.51,27.11 4.97,27.56 4.2,30.71 3.29,34.48 2.45,37.92 1.64,37.97 0.82,38 -0,38 -0.82,38 -1.64,37.97 -2.45,37.92 -3.29,34.48 -4.2,30.71 -4.97,27.56 -7.51,27.11 -9.93,26.31 -12.18,25.22 -14.65,27.32 -17.61,29.83 -20.31,32.12 -21.69,31.25 -23.02,30.28 -24.27,29.24 -22.92,25.96 -21.45,22.37 -20.22,19.37 -21.97,17.55 -23.47,15.49 -24.68,13.24 -27.91,13.49 -31.78,13.78 -35.32,14.05 -35.92,12.54 -36.42,10.99 -36.83,9.39 -33.81,7.53 -30.5,5.49 -27.75,3.79 -27.91,2.55 -28,1.29 -28,-0 -28,-1.29 -27.91,-2.55 -27.75,-3.79 -30.51,-5.49 -33.81,-7.53 -36.83,-9.39 -36.42,-10.99 -35.92,-12.54 -35.32,-14.05 -31.78,-13.78 -27.91,-13.49 -24.68,-13.24 -23.47,-15.49 -21.97,-17.55 -20.22,-19.37 -21.45,-22.37 -22.92,-25.96 -24.27,-29.24 -23.02,-30.28 -21.69,-31.25 -20.31,-32.12 -17.61,-29.83 -14.65,-27.32 -12.18,-25.22 -9.93,-26.31 -7.51,-27.11 -4.97,-27.56 -4.2,-30.71 -3.29,-34.48 -2.45,-37.92 -1.64,-37.97 -0.82,-38 0,-38 0.71,-38 1.42,-37.98 2.12,-37.94 Z M 0,-14 C -7.73,-14 -14,-7.73 -14,-0 -14,7.73 -7.73,14 0,14 7.73,14 14,7.73 14,-0 14,-5.48 10.85,-10.22 6.27,-12.52 4.38,-13.47 2.25,-14 0,-14 Z M 0,-14" transform="translate(62, 137) rotate(1)"  />
</svg>
```

What I am trying to sort out is how to click inside either `gears-largeGear` or `gears-smallGear` one or the other gear and drag the mouse to cause them to rotate similar to how the slider works.

Searching around it seems like Snap SVG is a good way to do this but I've struggled to bridge the SVG and the Snap documentation together. In Snap I see how to load the SVG but I don't quite see how to get the `path` or `group` to setup the interaction and rotation.

If I used groups like this `gears-largeGroup` and `gears-smallGroup` would it be the same sort of code as if it were just paths being animated?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="200"  xml:space="preserve" id="gears">
    <!-- Generated by PaintCode - http://www.paintcodeapp.com -->
    <g id="gears-largeGroup" transform="translate(149.59, 96.41)" >
        <path id="gears-largeGear" stroke="none" fill="rgb(69, 131, 212)" d="M 2.78,-67.94 C 3.71,-63.88 4.74,-59.43 5.59,-55.72 7.73,-55.51 9.84,-55.18 11.9,-54.73 13.87,-58 16.21,-61.91 18.36,-65.49 20.15,-64.99 21.91,-64.42 23.64,-63.78 23.27,-59.62 22.87,-55.08 22.54,-51.28 24.5,-50.42 26.4,-49.45 28.23,-48.37 31.11,-50.87 34.55,-53.87 37.69,-56.6 39.24,-55.58 40.73,-54.49 42.18,-53.34 40.55,-49.5 38.77,-45.3 37.28,-41.79 38.87,-40.37 40.37,-38.87 41.79,-37.28 45.3,-38.77 49.5,-40.55 53.34,-42.18 54.49,-40.73 55.58,-39.24 56.6,-37.69 53.87,-34.55 50.87,-31.11 48.37,-28.23 49.45,-26.4 50.42,-24.5 51.28,-22.54 55.08,-22.87 59.62,-23.27 63.78,-23.64 64.42,-21.91 64.99,-20.15 65.49,-18.36 61.91,-16.21 58,-13.87 54.73,-11.9 55.18,-9.84 55.51,-7.73 55.72,-5.59 59.43,-4.74 63.88,-3.71 67.94,-2.78 67.98,-1.86 68,-0.93 68,0 68,0.93 67.98,1.86 67.94,2.78 63.88,3.71 59.43,4.74 55.72,5.59 55.51,7.73 55.18,9.84 54.73,11.9 58,13.87 61.91,16.21 65.49,18.36 64.99,20.15 64.42,21.91 63.78,23.64 59.62,23.27 55.08,22.87 51.28,22.54 50.42,24.5 49.45,26.4 48.37,28.23 50.87,31.11 53.87,34.55 56.6,37.69 55.58,39.24 54.49,40.73 53.34,42.18 49.5,40.55 45.3,38.77 41.79,37.28 40.37,38.87 38.87,40.37 37.28,41.79 38.77,45.3 40.55,49.5 42.18,53.34 40.73,54.49 39.24,55.58 37.69,56.6 34.55,53.87 31.11,50.87 28.23,48.37 26.4,49.45 24.5,50.42 22.54,51.28 22.87,55.08 23.27,59.62 23.64,63.78 21.91,64.42 20.15,64.99 18.36,65.49 16.21,61.91 13.87,58 11.9,54.73 9.84,55.18 7.73,55.51 5.59,55.72 4.74,59.43 3.71,63.88 2.78,67.94 1.86,67.98 0.93,68 -0,68 -0.93,68 -1.86,67.98 -2.78,67.94 -3.71,63.88 -4.74,59.43 -5.59,55.72 -7.73,55.51 -9.84,55.18 -11.9,54.73 -13.87,58 -16.21,61.91 -18.36,65.49 -20.15,64.99 -21.91,64.42 -23.64,63.78 -23.27,59.62 -22.87,55.08 -22.54,51.28 -24.5,50.42 -26.4,49.45 -28.23,48.37 -31.11,50.87 -34.55,53.87 -37.69,56.6 -39.24,55.58 -40.73,54.49 -42.18,53.34 -40.55,49.5 -38.77,45.3 -37.28,41.79 -38.87,40.37 -40.37,38.87 -41.79,37.28 -45.3,38.77 -49.5,40.55 -53.34,42.18 -54.49,40.73 -55.58,39.24 -56.6,37.69 -53.87,34.55 -50.87,31.11 -48.37,28.23 -49.45,26.4 -50.42,24.5 -51.28,22.54 -55.08,22.87 -59.62,23.27 -63.78,23.64 -64.42,21.91 -64.99,20.15 -65.49,18.36 -61.91,16.21 -58,13.87 -54.73,11.9 -55.18,9.84 -55.51,7.73 -55.72,5.59 -59.43,4.74 -63.88,3.71 -67.94,2.78 -67.98,1.86 -68,0.93 -68,-0 -68,-0.93 -67.98,-1.86 -67.94,-2.78 -63.88,-3.71 -59.43,-4.74 -55.72,-5.59 -55.51,-7.73 -55.18,-9.84 -54.73,-11.9 -58,-13.87 -61.91,-16.21 -65.49,-18.36 -64.99,-20.15 -64.42,-21.91 -63.78,-23.64 -59.62,-23.27 -55.08,-22.87 -51.28,-22.54 -50.42,-24.5 -49.45,-26.4 -48.37,-28.23 -50.87,-31.11 -53.87,-34.55 -56.6,-37.69 -55.58,-39.24 -54.49,-40.73 -53.34,-42.18 -49.5,-40.55 -45.3,-38.77 -41.79,-37.28 -40.37,-38.87 -38.87,-40.37 -37.28,-41.79 -38.77,-45.3 -40.55,-49.5 -42.18,-53.34 -41.55,-53.84 -40.91,-54.33 -40.26,-54.81 -39.42,-55.43 -38.56,-56.03 -37.69,-56.6 -34.55,-53.87 -31.11,-50.87 -28.23,-48.37 -26.4,-49.45 -24.5,-50.42 -22.54,-51.28 -22.87,-55.08 -23.27,-59.62 -23.64,-63.78 -21.91,-64.42 -20.15,-64.99 -18.36,-65.49 -16.21,-61.91 -13.87,-58 -11.9,-54.73 -9.84,-55.18 -7.73,-55.51 -5.59,-55.72 -4.74,-59.43 -3.71,-63.88 -2.78,-67.94 -1.93,-67.98 -1.08,-68 -0.23,-68 L 0,-68 C 0.93,-68 1.86,-67.98 2.78,-67.94 Z M 0,-36 C -6.22,-36 -12.07,-34.42 -17.18,-31.65 -28.39,-25.55 -36,-13.66 -36,-0 -36,19.88 -19.88,36 0,36 19.88,36 36,19.88 36,-0 36,-19.88 19.88,-36 0,-36 Z M 0,-36" transform="rotate(-38)"  />
    </g>
    <g id="gears-smallGroup" transform="translate(62, 137)" >
        <path id="gears-smallGear" stroke="none" fill="rgb(115, 152, 218)" d="M 2.12,-37.94 L 2.45,-37.92 C 3.29,-34.48 4.2,-30.71 4.97,-27.56 6.23,-27.34 7.46,-27.03 8.65,-26.64 9.87,-26.24 11.04,-25.77 12.18,-25.22 14.65,-27.32 17.61,-29.83 20.31,-32.12 21.69,-31.25 23.02,-30.28 24.27,-29.24 22.92,-25.96 21.45,-22.37 20.22,-19.37 21.97,-17.55 23.47,-15.49 24.68,-13.24 27.91,-13.49 31.78,-13.78 35.32,-14.05 35.92,-12.54 36.42,-10.99 36.83,-9.39 33.81,-7.53 30.5,-5.49 27.75,-3.79 27.91,-2.55 28,-1.29 28,-0 28,1.29 27.91,2.55 27.75,3.79 30.51,5.49 33.81,7.53 36.83,9.39 36.42,10.99 35.92,12.54 35.32,14.05 31.78,13.78 27.91,13.49 24.68,13.24 23.47,15.49 21.97,17.55 20.22,19.37 21.45,22.37 22.92,25.96 24.27,29.24 23.02,30.28 21.69,31.25 20.31,32.12 17.61,29.83 14.65,27.32 12.18,25.22 9.93,26.31 7.51,27.11 4.97,27.56 4.2,30.71 3.29,34.48 2.45,37.92 1.64,37.97 0.82,38 -0,38 -0.82,38 -1.64,37.97 -2.45,37.92 -3.29,34.48 -4.2,30.71 -4.97,27.56 -7.51,27.11 -9.93,26.31 -12.18,25.22 -14.65,27.32 -17.61,29.83 -20.31,32.12 -21.69,31.25 -23.02,30.28 -24.27,29.24 -22.92,25.96 -21.45,22.37 -20.22,19.37 -21.97,17.55 -23.47,15.49 -24.68,13.24 -27.91,13.49 -31.78,13.78 -35.32,14.05 -35.92,12.54 -36.42,10.99 -36.83,9.39 -33.81,7.53 -30.5,5.49 -27.75,3.79 -27.91,2.55 -28,1.29 -28,-0 -28,-1.29 -27.91,-2.55 -27.75,-3.79 -30.51,-5.49 -33.81,-7.53 -36.83,-9.39 -36.42,-10.99 -35.92,-12.54 -35.32,-14.05 -31.78,-13.78 -27.91,-13.49 -24.68,-13.24 -23.47,-15.49 -21.97,-17.55 -20.22,-19.37 -21.45,-22.37 -22.92,-25.96 -24.27,-29.24 -23.02,-30.28 -21.69,-31.25 -20.31,-32.12 -17.61,-29.83 -14.65,-27.32 -12.18,-25.22 -9.93,-26.31 -7.51,-27.11 -4.97,-27.56 -4.2,-30.71 -3.29,-34.48 -2.45,-37.92 -1.64,-37.97 -0.82,-38 0,-38 0.71,-38 1.42,-37.98 2.12,-37.94 Z M 0,-14 C -7.73,-14 -14,-7.73 -14,-0 -14,7.73 -7.73,14 0,14 7.73,14 14,7.73 14,-0 14,-5.48 10.85,-10.22 6.27,-12.52 4.38,-13.47 2.25,-14 0,-14 Z M 0,-14" transform="rotate(-3)"  />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Would it be easier to do the mouse hit-test and interaction in Javascript instead of using Snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: SEE LOWER DOWN FOR IMPROVED METHOD**

Firstly, it may be easier to move the transform from the group in the 2nd example to the path. Then you can add any rotation transforms to the group without getting too messy. Eg.

```
<g id="gears-largeGroup"  >
    <path transform="translate(149.59, 96.41)" id="gears-largeGear".....
```

Once you have your SVG, you can select it in Snap with the Snap.select() method. This takes a css selector.

So we can find one with

```
Snap.select('#gears-smallGroup')
```

Now we have our gear, we can add a drag handler to it.

```
Snap.select('#gears-smallGroup').drag( dragRotate, dragStart )
```

So we just need to write our handler. Firstly we want to store the start of the drag (see updated solution at end, which is better), so we can write our startRotate function. This just stores an x,y object alongside the element.

```
function dragRotateStart( x, y ) {
  this.data('oxy', { x: x, y: y })
}
```

Then we can write the main drag rotation handler.
This takes the original start position oxy stored above, and adds it to the drags delta increments that is passes over.

Then we uses Snaps angle() method to calculate the angle between two points. One the x,y we just had, and the other the center of the element.

Now we have the angle, we can just do a rotation transform. Snap can use a shortform for a transform (r=rotation, t=translate, s=scale and r&s with Snap will transform from their centers unless specified).

So this becomes

```
function dragRotate( dx, dy, x, y ) {
  this.transform('r' + Snap.angle( this.getBBox().cx, this.getBBox().cy, dx + this.data('oxy').x, dy + this.data('oxy').y ) );
}
```

So whole code...

```
Snap.select('#gears-smallGroup').drag( dragRotate, dragRotateStart )  
Snap.select('#gears-largeGroup').drag( dragRotate, dragRotateStart ) 

function dragRotate( dx, dy, x, y ) {
  this.transform('r' + Snap.angle( this.getBBox().cx, this.getBBox().cy, dx + this.data('oxy').x, dy + this.data('oxy').y ) );
}

function dragRotateStart( x, y ) {
  this.data('oxy', { x: x, y: y })
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrpq977o/16/)

Now you have this, you can fiddle with it, so that one will rotate the other. You may also have to check the starting points after a redrag depending on where your new drag starts from.

(quick stab at making smaller gear rotate bigger one [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrpq977o/17/))

**UPDATED AND IMPROVED VERSION**:

Extending this further, you will need to adapt it, to take into account both the starting rotation (also if it's pre-rotated) and the starting angle in the drag, we only want the difference in angles, so it doesn't reset.

So we can store out starting bits. What angle was the start of the drag at (I've set default to 10 as the image dot was offset by about 10deg). What was the old rotation of the element.

```
function dragRotateStart(x, y) {
  this.data('startingAngle', Snap.angle(this.getBBox().cx, this.getBBox().cy, x, y));
  this.data('startingRotation', this.data('rotation')||10)
}
```

And then calculate the correct rotation from the starting rotation, plus the angle difference, storing it as we go (so if we drag again later, we know what its last rotation was)...

```
function dragRotate(dx, dy, x, y) {
  var angleDiff = Snap.angle(this.getBBox().cx, this.getBBox().cy, x, y) - this.data('startingAngle')
  var newRotation = angleDiff + +this.data('startingRotation');
  this.data('rotation', newRotation)
  this.transform('r' + newRotation); 
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w14hqtnc/6/)

Comment: Awesome, how would I separate the SVG into it's own file from the HTML content? Is that just with the normal `Snap.load` command?

Comment: I tried it and the load works just fine with your sample code.

Comment: I notice that depending on where the gear is clicked the rotation will jump quite a bit. For instance if you click 180 degrees from the previous release point the gear will jump 180 degrees with a single pixel drag. I think it is related to how (x,y) is stored initially and then applied to the transformation on the initial drag.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, I would also double check things like having a second click which goes over the 360deg line. That may not be related, but often rotations need a bit of extra checking as rotations aren't continuous when it goes 359->360->0. So basically check the angle on the first dragstart and then the next, see if there's an edge case which is tripping it up. I was just trying to get you most of the way.

Comment: Thanks Ian your answer is fantastic. Yes, I am researching the issue and will post here when I find the answer. In this case it is not related to the 360->0 transition, since I can get the jump with just a few degrees offset from release point.. But I am not sure of more than that yet.

Comment: I think you need to think about how you want the logic to work. It may be simpler to try it with a rect for example to make it more obvious. Suppose you drag it 45deg. Next drag, you probably will want it to be the previous angle (45) + some change of the drag (eg 15).